# Mi evento keydown dejo de funcionar cuando agregue .emojiArea al input del formulario web

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat-entry" placeholder="Escriba un mensaje y presione enter para enviar">
```

Función para llamar al evento y enviar automaticamente los datos de ingreso:

```js
this.chatEntry.keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 32) {
        e.preventDefault();
        self._sendMessage({
            name: self.chatName.val(),
            message: self.chatEntry.val()
        });
        self.chatEntry.val("");
    }           
});
```

Función para agregar emojis en el input :

```js
<script>
    ($('.chat-entry')).emojioneArea({
        pickerPosition: "top"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Normalmente se ponen las etiquetas relacionadas con el problema. Aquí  no veo nada de java ni jsp.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.body.innerHTML = `
    <input type="text">`;

    let inp = document.querySelector('input');
    inp.addEventListener('keydown',(e)=>{
        if(e.key == 'Enter'){
            console.log('hola')
        }
    });
```

He probado como tu lo hacías, con el `e.keyCode === 32` y no funciona, al menos con la solución que te puse yo se puede mandar.